# A word for intentionally losing a bet?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Is there a word, or phrase, to express when someone makes a bet with the intent to lose?

I’m looking for one of two things (or both). Either a verb to express the action of making such a bet, or a word that is defined by this specific type of bet.

An example would be in Seinfeld: Elaine makes a bet with a guy, and if the guy “loses” he must buy her dinner (with the assumption being he made a bet knowing he would lose).

I realize this is basically just a swindle, but I’m hoping there is something more specific.

Comment: I have seen 'donating' used

Comment: I have seen 'tank' used

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're *[throwing](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/throw)* it, like a fight.

> :  to lose intentionally

Comment: I like this answer, but how would you write a sentence using the term? "Elaine threw the bet." That's not right, is it?

Comment: @JLG looks fine to me.

Comment: @JLG, I think it perfectly [cromulent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cromulent)  :)

Comment: "Elaine threw the bet" exactly captures what you're going for here.

Comment: @cornbread ninja, humorous comment. (I guess I was just thinking the "it" in your answer stood for something other than "the bet.") +1

Answer (score 3):

This may not fit with your example, but *[sandbagging](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sandbag?region=us&q=sandbag)* is a term for intentionally losing (a bet, game, match, etc.) in order to gain advantage later.

Comment: Sandbagging is more descriptive of the act of doing badly, while throwing describes the intent of losing a contest on purpose. You might sandbag but still win (for example, to conceal your actual talent level and keep your opponent willing to continue.)

Comment: Sandbags are also used as a ballast in balloons. When a balloon starts to lose some of its buoyancy, due to the cooling of hot air or escape of gas, sandbags can be tossed out of he balloon to lighten the load. It may be from this meaning that the term is derived: an initial disadvantage (heavier aircraft) turns to an advantage later (staying airborne).

Comment: @Kaz: That's a theory I haven't heard before (and there are plenty of them out there). It would make a good question, I think.

Answer (score 1):

*Hustle* might work (both as a verb and noun), especially if the context makes it clear that you are being playful. A couple of [meanings are:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hustle)

> To misrepresent one's ability in order to deceive someone, especially in gambling; to misrepresent one's skill in (a game or activity) in order to deceive someone, especially in gambling: *hustle pool*.

You could say, "Elaine hustled dinner from a guy."

Comment: This is also what leapt to my mind.

Comment: I also thought of hustle but the OP's question seemed to imply the bet was "one and done"; hustling usually means that you do badly for a while and then start doing *well* after your opponent has underestimated your ability.

Answer (score 1):

Deliberately losing a fight or some other contest is also called *taking a dive*.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest word or phrase in common usage is [*long shot*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/long+shot) (a bet made at great odds). I wouldn't necessarily say that it is used when you intend to lose but rather when you are likely to lose in an honest contest, regardless of intent. If the outcome is certain and the contest is [*fixed*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fixed) then the betting/gambling aspect is removed and now you're just [*throwing*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/throwing) the bet.

Using your example: *Elaine was certain that she was going to dinner with this guy; winning was going to be a **long shot** for him and she knew it. She just hoped he didn't figure it out first. Elaine had been dying to try the calamari at El Zapato for weeks and this guy was just the window dressing for the occasion.*

Answer (score 0):

In gambling terms, **backing** describes betting 'for' something to happen.

Betting 'against' something happening, e.g. betting a horse does *not* win is known as a **lay** bet (or simply **laying**).

So to use the example in the question, you could say Elaine is placing a ***lay*** bet that the guy achieves whatever the bet stipulates - essentially ***backing*** him to fail.