# Is there a single word to describe deliberately losing with the best hand in a card game?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want a single word to describe deliberately losing with the best hand in a card game.

Comment: Does it have to be a card game? What about a metaphor, like "taking a dive"?

Comment: Why do you think there is a single word for it?

Comment: It's called throwing a race in the horsing world.

Comment: Somewhat related       https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65806/a-word-for-intentionally-losing-a-bet

Comment: Believe it or not, *folding the nuts*, though it’s not a single word.  The *nuts* are the best possible hole cards for a particular hand and the only way to actually lose when you hold the nuts is to fold: any other play, by definition, results in your win (though it’s possible that some hands have two or more sets of nut cards, so you could end up splitting the pot).

Comment: @DanBron: This is what the player has done, but you can also accidentally fold the nuts.

Comment: Why is the person losing the game? Does it give them some strategic value in a later game? Is it to make the other person feel a certain way? Something else?

Comment: @DanBron *"folding the nuts"*... My first day back and you're already teaching me new things. I see you're still on top of your game.

Comment: @DanBron *the nuts* is a unbeatable hand, but the phase *folding the nuts* is unrelated to whether it was on purpose or accidental. The question seems focused on the *deliberate* aspect so I don’t think that phrase works.

Answer (score 3):

General term (not just for card games): ***[tank](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tank)***.

> 1 : to make no effort to win : lose intentionally • ***tanked*** the match
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tank)*</sub>

Comment: "Unlike the Saints and Panthers, who need to win Sunday, the Rams can afford to tank the 49ers game."—jeff duncan, *NOLA.com,* "Saints face dilemma Sunday: Win vs. Bucs could set up playoff date in Minnesota," 28 Dec. 2017  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tank
"

Comment: Tanking in cards, especially Poker, has a different meaning.  It means to take a very long time to make a decision so this term would be very confusing. https://www.poker-king.com/dictionary/tank/

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say is simply a type of *cheating*, but perhaps if it’s poker you could say the person is *chip dumping*.

> **Chip Dumping.**
>   word type: verb.
>
> Intentionally losing chips to another player for the purposes of cheating. This subterfuge is not permitted online and is ethically questionable.
>   - http://pokerterms.com/chip-dumping.html

Comment: But why cheat to lose?

Comment: @Kris Giving another player your chips can give him a big advantage in a poker tournament; and since prize money is weighted toward the top place finishers, it can have a overall (combined) improved expected value for the two players.